# How to make a choice when there is doubt between a variable being categorical or continuous?

Tags: categorical-data, continuous-data

I have an instagram dataset. Often the caption contains tags (@person_x). I counted the amount of tags per post but now can't choose wether to use it as a continuous variable or categorical. I know the amount of tags is finite (it never goes past 5) and you cannot tag 5,5 persons for example. The reason I am doubting is because I have another variable that also it finite (never goes beyond 8), namely days_since_last_post (I know that this value could be 7,57 if I accounted for hours and such, but I don't).

So my question is if there is some rule of thumb on this?

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing "categorical" with "discrete"?   The number of airplanes that land at Heathrow in a day is discrete (being an integer), not continuous, and definitely not categorical.   "Smoking / non-smoking" is an example of a categorical variable.

Answer (score 1):

A count* is neither continuous nor categorical. A number of books seem to treat "continuous" and "categorical" as some kind of dichotomy, but this isn't the case at all.

* nor indeed discrete random variables more generally.

Days since last post is clearly not categorical either; you're right that it might possibly be treated as either discrete or continuous, depending on circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

A simple rule of thumb is: if two values in a column were 2 and 4, would you consider the latter to be twice the magnitude of the first one? If so that’s continuous. I’m not an instagram user, I don’t know if 5 is an IG imposed limit of tagged users, but I would think that most likely you would treat as continuous. 
You may want to add a binary category for when there are no tagged users depending on your purpose.